# Jersey throws NullPointerException when parsing corrupt request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

When sending a request with content type *multipart/mixed* but corrupt body (one that is no multipart), Jersey throws a `NullPointerException` while parsing the request.

```
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
public Response someResource(MultiPart multiPart) { ... }
```

This results in a status code 500, while 4xx would be correct. How can I handle this exception without catching all `NullPointerExceptions`?

Attachment A: stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.unquoteMediaTypeParameters(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:227)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:154)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:82)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.yammer.metrics.jersey.InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TimedRequestDispatcher.dispatch(InstrumentedResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:32)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter.doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

Comment: Why didn't you post the stack trace of your NPE?

Comment: @isnot2bad I added the stacktrace

Comment: What does the class or method `@Produces`?

Comment: @lutz Produces doesn't matter. The method is never called, since the NPE happens prior in the jersey framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This seems to be a bug in Jersey](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1658). They don't check the "boundary" parameter value for `null`, before dereferencing it. You will have to find a workaround until it is fixed.

**Workaround 1: Provide an `ExceptionMapper`**

Maybe you can register an `ExceptionMapper` for `NullPointerException` and inspect the stack trace to test, if it is that bug or any other NPE. In case of this bug, return `4xx`, otherwise as usual `500 - internal server error`. (It's a bad hack, but I think that's ok for a temporary workaround).

**Workaround 2: Provide a JAX-RS `ContainerRequestFilter`**

Since JAX-RS 2.0, it is possible to provide a `ContainerRequestFilter` that is invoked before the resource method is called. Check the boundary parameter in the `Content-Type` request header. If it is absent, abort the request by calling `ContainerRequestContext#abortWith(Reponse)`.

**Workaround 3: Write a servlet filter**

Similar to workaround 2, but with good-old `javax.servlet.Filter`. Make sure, the filter is called before Jersey processes the request.

Comment: Maybe you could add a servlet filter that rejects multi part requests without boundary parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The NPE occurs because the boundary parameter is missing in your call. I ran into the same problem and needed to fix the issue for my service. I ended up manually adding the boundary parameter to the Content-Type header that Jersey is expecting

https://servicesunavailable.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/using-apache-httpclient-4-x-for-multipart-uploads-with-jersey-1-x-server/

The fix is not pretty since the class MultipartFormEntity is package private however it works well.

Comment: I fixed it by setting the boundary with HTTP client: `MultipartEntityBuilder.create()                                                 .setBoundary("boundary")` and setting manually `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=boundary`